# How to connect to stun and turn servers using simple peer

Tags: socket.io, webrtc, stun, turn, simple-peer

I developed a video chatting application using simple peer and socket.io . But when I tried hosting the application the peers could not be connected because of the firewall issue . I am aware that STUN and TURN servers are to be used for this purpose . Is it possible to connect to those servers using simple peer ?
If so how?
Any explanation or reference articles will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can add the iceServer configuration like in [original webrtc](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/turn-server) in the [simple-peer config](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer) like so:

```
{
  initiator: false,
  config: { iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }, { urls: 'stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp' }] },
}
```

You can add stun servers and/or turn servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the source code of the `simple-peer` npm package you will realize that it currently uses

```
URLs: [
  'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
  'stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478'
]
```

for its public IP discovery needs.

Your app fails to work in case of firewall because just `stun` server is insufficient in case of firewall.

Besides a `STUN` server, you need a `TURN` server is this case.

`TURN` is the fallback is case `STUN` fails to deliver.