# Why does my simple peer WebRTC work on some android phones but not others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, simplewebrtc

I built a chat react app as a PWA that works on desktops and works on my phone and my wife's phone but not on some other androids and not on Iphones. I was wondering if anyone knew of why that might be. I have also had cases where it get connected but I cannot see video or audio and cases where it connects one time but I can try another day and it wont connect. I thought it may have something to do with the trickle being set to false or maybe I need to update my simple peer API right now I have 9.7 but I see they have a 9.10.
one thought I had is  that it works fine for my wife and I because we are on the same network.

```
import React from "react";

import Peer from "simple-peer";
import SocketContext from "../../context/SocketProvider";




let phoneRinging = new Audio("./phoneRing.mp3")

class VideoChat extends React.Component {

static contextType = SocketContext
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.socket = createRef();
    this.state = {
        yourInfo: this.props.yourInfo,
        users: this.props.users,
        stream: null,
        receivingCall: this.props.receivingCall,
        caller: this.props.caller,
        callerSignal: this.props.callerSignal,
        callAccepted: false,
        btnHidden: false

    };
}

componentDidMount() {

    this.getVideo()

}

getVideo = () => {

    const contraints = {
        audio: true,
        video: true
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(contraints)

        .then(stream => {

            console.log(stream)


            let video = document.getElementById("senderVid");
            video.srcObject = stream;

            this.setState({ stream: stream })
        })

        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err, alert("cannot access your camera"))
        });



}


callPeer = (id) => {
    const socket = this.context
    //    this.phoneRingFn()
    const peer = new Peer({
        initiator: true,
        trickle: false,
        stream: this.state.stream,

    });
    console.log(peer)

    peer.on("signal", data => {

        socket.emit("callUser", { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: this.state.yourInfo })
        console.log("call placed")
    })

    peer.on("stream", stream => {
        let video = document.getElementById("recVid");
        video.srcObject = stream;
    });

    socket.on("callAccepted", signal => {
        this.setState({ callAccepted: true })
        phoneRinging.pause()
        phoneRinging.currentTime = 0;
        peer.signal(signal);
    })


}


acceptCall = () => {
    const socket = this.context
    // phoneRinging.pause()
    // phoneRinging.currentTime = 0;
    this.setState({ callAccepted: true })
    console.log("1")
    const peer = new Peer({
        initiator: false,
        trickle: false,
        stream: this.state.stream,
    });
    peer.on("signal", data => {
        console.log("2")
        console.log(this.state.caller)

        socket.emit("acceptCall", { signal: data, to: this.state.caller.socketId })
    })

    peer.on("stream", stream => {
        console.log("3")
        let video = document.getElementById("recVid");
        video.srcObject = stream;
    });

    peer.signal(this.state.callerSignal);
    this.setState({ btnHidden: true })



}

hangUp = () => {
    this.props.callEnded()


    document.getElementById("recVid").remove()

}

phoneRingFn = () => {

    phoneRinging.play()
    console.log("phone ringing ")
    let timesPhnRung = 0
    let MaxRings = 3

    phoneRinging.onplay = function () {
        //played counter
        timesPhnRung++;
    };

    phoneRinging.addEventListener("ended", function () {

        phoneRinging.currentTime = 0;
        if (timesPhnRung < MaxRings) {
            phoneRinging.play();
        } else {
            timesPhnRung = 0;

        }
    });



}
// peer.on("close",()=>{
//     console.log("peerdestroy")
//     document.getElementById("recVid").remove()
//     peer.destroy();

//   })


render() {
    console.log(this.state.btnHidden)
    console.log(this.props)

    let incomingCall;
    if (this.state.receivingCall) {
        incomingCall = ((this.state.btnHidden === false) ?
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.caller.name} is calling you</h1>
                <button onClick={this.acceptCall}>Accept</button>
            </div> :
            <div><h1>call connected</h1></div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className="videoChatContainer">
            <div className="videoWindows">
                <div className="senderVidContainer">
                    sender
           <video id="senderVid" className="senderVideo" autoPlay="autoplay" muted></video>
                </div>
                <div className="receiverVidContainer">
                    receiver
           <video id="recVid" className="receiverVideo" autoPlay="autoplay"></video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button className="disconnectChat" onClick={() => this.hangUp()}>end call</button>
            { !this.state.receivingCall ? (
                <div>{
                    this.state.users.length ? (

                        <div>{
                            this.state.users.map(identify =>

                                (identify.userid === this.props.friendsPhId) ?

                                    <button onClick={() => this.callPeer(identify.socketId)}>Call {identify.name}</button>

                                    : null
                            )}
                        </div>
                    ) : (<h1>Loading</h1>)}
                </div>
            ) : (<div></div>)}
            <div>
                {incomingCall}
            </div>
        </div>



    )



    }



  }

export default VideoChat;
```

Comment: Are you using a STUN and TURN server? Depending on what networks these devices are in P2P connectivity might not be possible.

Comment: I was just using the simple peer package

Comment: Ok, you need to use TURN servers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62666458/5472819 not all connection pairings will work without them unfortunately.

Comment: I added the Turn servers but the docs aren't clear this is what I have